# Automatic scrolling to bottom when Subscribe on Footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I am in the footer and submit the form, it will redirect to another page but it automatically srcoll to the footer

Now I want it to not scroll, is there any way? I try to us window.scrollToTop but it not working, it still scroll to bottom then scroll to top after that

Comment: share the code!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening only in chrome browser!

Can you try adding following auto scroll restriction in your head tag?

```js
<script>
  window.history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
</script>
```

Setting to value manual will not auto scroll on page load/reload.

reference :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration